# preloading viewcontroller for location of barbutton item

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have viewController A
It will present viewController B
I will be layering viewController C over viewController B (tutorial layover)
In order for me to point an arrow image on vc C to an element on vc B I need to know where that element is.

When I try to lay vc C over B to prepare for the animation from vc A to vc B, vc B is not yet laid out because it has not yet been presented. Therefor vc C can't properly place it's arrow image pointing to the element on vc B.

view.setNeedsLayout() and view.layoutIfNeeded() do not work as this only triggers viewDidLoad and viewDidLayout subviews not viewDidAppear. I've tested this and the element I am looking to point to (bar button item) is still not laid out after calling these.

Is there a way to completely layout a viewcontroller in the background before it is presented? I believe this would solve my problem.

**update**

I want to force draw/layout a view controller

maybe with `tbVC.view.setNeedsLayout()` and `tbVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()` ?

Then I want a completion block telling me when this is done.
Then I want to execute some code which accesses the drawn elements (uibuttonbaritem) within completion block.
And I want all of this to be done in the background without presenting the view controller.

Cheers!

Comment: how about adding an subview of C in B?

Comment: Are you presenting C after viewDidAppear in B ?

Comment: No, but that is what I am trying to do. However I do not want to do this from vc B itself as I don't want this executed every time that view controller loads.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you need **ViewController C as subview of ViewController B** and you need to call ViewController B from ViewContrller A

```
self.view.addSubView(vcC.view) //instead of vcB use your ViewControler C instance
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: As of right now I am adding vc C as a subview of vc B. However, when I call 'setArrowToPointToVCBButtonBar' in vc C's view did load it cannot find the location of vc B button bar item because it hasn't loaded yet. I almost need like a callback from from vc B to tell me when it's view elements are loaded, then to execute the 'setArrowToPointToVCBButtonBar' in the completion block of that callback. Does this make sense?

Comment: It's as if I could call `tbVC.view.setNeedsLayout()` and `tbVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()` to force draw vc B, then have a completion block telling me when that was done, then execute 'setArrowToPointToVCBButtonBar' within that block. All this done off screen before the animation starts. That is ideally what I am looking to do.